# Custom css-class on AngularJS datepicker buttons if date is in $scope

Tags: css, angularjs, date, datepicker

In my `AngularJS` app I have a `$scope` like this

**controller.js**

```
$scope.takeovers = {
    "_id":"5640989531622c5c28fd41c7",
    "activationDate":[{
        "start":"2015-10-31T23:00:00.000Z",
        "end":"2015-11-05T23:00:00.000Z",
        "_id":"5640989531622c5c28fd41cc"
    }],
    "_id":"5640a14a1a743d001a3a1c94",
    "activationDate":[{
        "start":"2015-11-07T23:00:00.000Z",
        "end":"2015-11-05T23:00:00.000Z",
        "_id":"2015-11-12T23:00:00.000Z"
    }]
}
```

In the view I generate a `datepicker` with the following options

**index.jade**

```
datepicker( ng-model="upcoming" 
            show-weeks="false" 
            ng-click='selectTakeover(upcoming)' 
            custom-class='getDayClass(date)')
```

Now I would like to have the `getDayClass(date)` function compare the `date` with `$scope.activationDate` `start` and `end` and if the `date` is between `start` and `end` return a css-class called `highlight-current-date`

```
$scope.getDayClass = function(date) {

    //The date object contains ISO-date from datepicker option "custom-class"
    //Here I want to compare date with $scope.activationDate to see if date is 
    //between $scope.activationDate.start and $scope.activationDate.end.

    //I know I need to re-format the dates to be able to match them. 
    //This can be done using $filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd:hh:mm')
    // if match then var result = 'highlight-current-date';

    return result;
}
```

I have tried to pass the `date` to an `angular.forEach` function that iterates over the `$scope.takeovers` but I was unable to return a working class since the result is beeing overwritten every time `forEach` iterates and I was unable to break it.

Comment: The object in `$scope.takeovers` looks a bit surprising, not an array you can iterate easily. Shouldn't it be something like
`$scope.takeovers = [ {...}, {...} ];`

Comment: Good point. Maybe I should re-format my scope to only list date it should be active

Comment: If you had a an array of objects it would be easy to iterate over it. If you need to break from it just use a for loop. Or you can use Array.prototype.filter to find only those objects which are suitable.